If $X$ is a hyperbolic, locally finite graph with $\partial X \cong S^1$, and $G$ acts cocompactly but not properly on $X$, what can we say?
It is an important and deep fact of geometric group theory that if the Gromov boundary of a hyperbolic group $G$ is a circle, then $G$ is virtually Fuchsian [Tukia, Gabai, Casson-Jungreis...]. I am interested in the following slightly more general question:
Let $X$ be a connected, locally finite, hyperbolic graph such that $\partial X$ is a circle. Suppose that $G$ is a group acting cocompactly (but not properly) on $X$.

Question. Does there necessarily exist Fuchsian $H \leq G$ acting properly and cocompactly on $X$?

Perhaps this can be seen by piecing together known results, but I have not had much luck.
As an aside, some evidence this should be true is the following theorem [1]:

Theorem. If $X$ is a connected, locally finite graph with quadratic growth and $Aut(G)$ acts on $X$ cocompactly, then there exists $\mathbb Z^2 \leq Aut(G)$ acting properly and cocompactly on $X$.

Any references are appreciated!

[1] Seifter, N., & Trofimov, V. I. (1997). Automorphism groups of graphs with quadratic growth. Journal of combinatorial theory, Series B, 71(2), 205-210.

[Edit: I have corrected the statement of Seifter-Trofimov's theorem]

I think $G$ is an extension of a Fuchsian group by a profinite group. Such extension need not split. Now consider Cayley graphs of nontrivial central extensions of Fuchsian groups by finite groups.

The question doesn’t say so, but presumably you want to assume that $G$ acts faithfully.

@MoisheKohan: every extension of a Fuchsian group by a finite group is residually finite (because Fuchsian groups are good in the sense of Serre) and hence virtually torsion-free. So I believe these kinds of examples do contain a surface subgroup acting cocompactly.

@HJRW: Oh, of course...

By the way the fact about $\mathbf{Z}^2$ is false. Maybe Seifton-Trofimov assume that the action is faithful.

@MoisheKohan: It seems to me your first assertion implies that the result is positive for finitely generated $G$ acting faithfully. Indeed, every countable profinite group is finite, so we are in the case handled above. The OP hasn’t indicated whether they are interested in the fg case (or confirmed that they want to add the “faithful” hypothesis, which is obviously necessary). But this positive answer seems worth recording. Do you have a reference for your assertion?

@YCor Thanks for pointing that out about the $\mathbb Z^2$ fact. I checked again and the result is that $Aut(X)$ (which certainly acts faithfully) contains $\mathbb Z^2$ acting cocompactly (and necessarily properly). The proof should hold for any faithful, cocompact action, mind. I will correct this in the question.

@HJRW No, this is not what Moishe said. If $X$ is the given graph, its automorphism group $G$ has a unique maximal compact normal subgroup $W$ and $G/W$ is discrete Fuchsian (cocompact in $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{R})$. The kernel $W$ acts with orbits of bounded size, so is a very special kind of profinite group (embeddable into $F^\mathbf{N}$ for some finite group $F$). Now, for a discrete (non-proper) faithful action, you get a subgroup of $G$, possibly dense. It is an extension of a (bounded torsion locally finite) group by a Fuchsian group; It's unclear to me whether this virtually splits.

@YCor: ah, the assertion is just that the kernel is locally finite with bounded torsion? That’s much less useful, of course. An example showing it needn’t split would be great.

@HJRW thanks for pointing out the necessity of assuming faithfulness. I’m secretly interested in the automorphism group of $X$, so faithful but not necessarily finitely generated. I agree the f.g. case is interesting in its own right, however.

@HJRW Well, it's not "just" this. The compact kernel preserves a partition of the graph with bounded finite components. So it embeds into some power of a finite group, and in particular is locally finite of bounded torsion. But conversely there is no reason to believe that any extension of this form possesses a faithful action on a graph preserving such a partition.

What is true is that $G$ has a compact normal subgroup with Fuchsian quotient.
First, let $G$ be the isometry group and $W$ the kernel of the action on the Gromov boundary. Then $W$ is compact (as true for every nonelementary hyperbolic group). So $G/W$ acts faithfully continuously on the circle, and the 1-dimensional case of the Smith conjecture, which is an easy theorem, implies that $G/W$ is Lie. But here $G$ is also totally disconnected, so $G/W$ is discrete. Hence $G/W$ is a discrete hyperbolic group whose boundary is a topological circle, and by the work of the authors you're mentioning (Tukia, Gabai, Casson-Jungreis), $G/W$ is isomorphic to a cocompact lattice in $\mathrm{Isom}(\mathbf{H}^2)=\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{R})$.
If $G$ is an arbitrary totally disconnected locally compact Gromov-hyperbolic group with circle Gromov boundary, however, not true that there exists a cocompact lattice in $G$. For instance, let $\Gamma$ be the inverse image of a genus $g\ge 2$ surface group in $\widetilde{\mathrm{SL}_2}$. This is the group with presentation with $2g$ generators $a_1,\dots,b_g$ and the relators expressing that $z=\prod [a_i,b_i]$ is central. Let $G$ be the quotient of $G\times\mathbf{Z}_p$ ($p$-adics) identifying $z$ with the generator of $\mathbf{Z}_p$. Then $G$ has no cocompact lattice.
I have to think twice to get such $G$ to be the cocompact automorphism group of a graph.

But the question asks for a subgroup, not a quotient…

That said, if the conclusion is that $G$ is Fuchsian-by-finite, then one can conclude that $G$ contains a cocompact surface subgroup of finite index, as I explained in a comment above.

@HJRW the conclusion is that $G$ is compact-by-(discrete Fuchsian). This can fail to have a cocompact lattice (I provided an example).

Thank you - does this Fuchsian quotient also act on $X$?

@jpmacmanus Not necessarily. It acts on a quotient of $X$, namely by some equivalence relation with uniformly bounded equivalence classes (so that the quotient map is a quasi-isometry).

Is there a finitely generated counterexample?

@HJRW Yes (as soon as one doesn't require faithfulness of the action). Just take a free group surjecting onto a surface group, and get a non-faithful Fuchsian action.

Well, that’s trivial. Obviously faithfulness should be assumed.

@HJRW So, there is no f.g. counterexample with proper action, because of Serre's property (that every central extension with surface group quotient and finite kernel virtually splits). For a f.g. example I don't know (I didn't solve the question for faithful actions, even for proper actions of locally compact groups).

So, to be clear, the example in your answer isn’t faithful? So it’s no better than a surjection from a free group to a surface group?

@HJRW It's better (in my sense), because it's a proper action. But it's not faithful.

@YCor I want to understand this properly - when you say that $G$ has a compact normal subgroup with Fuchsian quotient, are you assuming faithfulness here? If not, can we say something stronger if we do assume this?

@jpmacmanus yes: by Fuchsian quotient I mean a group isomorphic to a cocompact lattice in $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{R})$.
